# jQuery interdependent sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

http://oi42.tinypic.com/2myduur.jpg

I have sliders: "quantity", "unitprice", "discount"

If I slide quantity(quantity have value X), I need to change slider "unitprice" value = X+5.

```
$(".quantity_{/literal}{$value['idProduct']}{literal}").empty().slider({
orientation: "vertical",
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
value: 0,
slide: function(event, ui)
{
$("#quantity_{/literal}{$value['idProduct']}{literal}").val(ui.value);
}
}).bind('slide slidechange', function(event,ui) {
/* Here is the problem, Here i can set value on slider change for input fields and other, but for slider I cant */ });
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
 $(".selector").slider("value", parseInt(ui.value)+5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello from the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

```
$(".selector").slider("option", "value", 10);
```

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/kdPZt/3/

Comment: I was try that, doesnt work, I have error: "cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization attempted to call method 'value'"

Comment: Thanks to you (16tJYmDyCtuDoQxaQcUNEHiqzwMHggvTPr my first btc ^^) ;) Can you mark your question to resolved ?